# TextField accepts only one letter and loses focus

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have this component where I have a Textfield `organizationName` for the user to input its name. I include this textfield to a router to display when a specific route matches this.

However, when I include it to this router, the Textfield just bugs and lets me type only one letter after getting unfocused. I have to then type the next letter again and again. I assume it's the way I import this of something. Any help would mean a lot.

I am using `material-UI` and `react-routerv4`

```
const [organizationName, setOrganizationName] = useState('')
```

```
const handleChange = (event) => {
    setOrganizationName(event.target.value)
  }
```

This is the Textfield function that I import:

```
 const addOrganizationView = () => {
    return (
      <div className={content}>
        <h1 className={header}>Organization Setup</h1>
        <div className={organizationFormWrapper}>
          <TextField
            label='Organization Name'
            variant='outlined'
            name='organizationName'
            className={textField}
            value={organizationName}
            onChange={(event) => handleChange(event)}
          />
          <Button
            variant='contained'
            color='primary'
            className={addOrganizationButton}
            onClick={(event) => handleOrganizationAdd(event)}
            startIcon={<SaveIcon />}
          >
            Save
          </Button>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

This is the router

```
<div className={container}>
  <CustomizedStepper />
    <Switch>
      <Route
        path='/setup-organization'
          exact
          component={addOrganizationView}
        />
      <Route
        exact
        path='/setup-organization/invite'
        component={InvitationPage}
      />
   </Switch>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `<Route>` with the `component` prop, and you pass it a function, you create a new component on every render. So loses focus when that component is recreated.

What you want to do is use the `render` prop and pass it the function instead.

> When you use component (instead of render or children, below) the
>   router uses React.createElement to create a new React element from the
>   given component. That means if you provide an inline function to the
>   componentprop, you would create a new component every render. This
>   results in the existing component unmounting and the new component
>   mounting instead of just updating the existing component. When using
>   an inline function for inline rendering, use the render or the
>   children prop (below).

https://medium.com/@migcoder/difference-between-render-and-component-prop-on-react-router-v4-368ca7fedbec

```
<Route 
  path='/setup-organization'
  exact
  render={addOrganizationView}
/>
```

Comment: This did it. Thank you so much!